# A simple list question

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

If I have `list1={x^a, x^b, x^c}` and `list2={1,2,3}`, how do I substitute one into the other to get `{1^a, 2^b, 3^c}`  ? ie. substitution of x

Edit: I need help with a more complicated example. Namely this:

If I have `list1={e^(u[1]+a[1]), e^(u[2]+a[2]), e^(u[3]+a[3])}` and `list2={1,2,3}`, how do I substitute one into the other to get `{e^(1+a[1]), e^(2+a[2]), e^(3+a[3])}` ? ie. substitution of u[i]

Comment: Use `MapThread` with pure functions: `MapThread[#1 /. x -> #2 &, {list1, list2}]`.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. Its a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours** before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part.

Answer (score 10):

```
MapThread[#1 /. x -> #2 &, {list1, list2}]
```

Answer (score 8):

### Response to the edit:

It's easy to adapt my 2nd and 3rd approach below to meet your requirement:

```
l = list1; l[[;; , 2, 2]] = list2; l

i = 1; list1 /. u[_] :> list2[[i++]]
```

---

### Original Answer:

Shortest so far:

```
list2^list1[[;; , 2]]
```

---

2nd shortest so far:

```
l = list1; l[[;; , 1]] = list2; l
```

If `l` isn't introduced to keep `list1` unaltered, it'll be another shortest one.

---

3rd shortest so far:

```
i = 1; list1 /. x :> list2[[i++]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
MapThread[Function[x, #][#2] &, {list1, list2}]
```